# NoClassDefFoundError when code moved from R2007a to R2013a

Tags: java, matlab

I am working on moving code from R2007a to R2013a. I am getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError during my run in R2013a which does not appear in R2007a. It occurs when I call.

> feval('get',fname,jevent);

Where `fname` is a `product.ProxyField` object for an Object Filter and `jevent` is a `product.format.java.internal.JavaEvent`.
The class is in a jar file on the path and is being accessed by another class in the same jar file. The stack trace does not leave the realm of the product if that helps.

I do not have access to the original code for the jar file. I do have access to code derived from that original code and both classes are in the same package. I'm guessing this has something to do with differences in the java version but I'm not sure what to do since I don't have the original code to recompile.

Unfortunately I can't provide actual source or full detail but a google search only yielded results for MATLAB startup issues. Any thoughts?

Comment: We're gonna need a LOT more detail. You say "moving code" but then you say you don't have access to the original code. What jar are you moving?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not moving the jar files I'm working on getting MATLAB code that was working on R2007a to work on R2013a. Some of that code calls java methods and that's where I get the error. I don't have access to the code from which the jar files were compiled but I do have the MATLAB code which is calling it.

Comment: Please provide code in the original post that causes the error mentioned. There's way to many options right now.

Comment: Your question is lacking in specifics. You need to detail what code/package this is, what "related product" this is, how exactly its being called in the code you do have. Otherwise, StackOverflow is less helpful than Google.

Comment: The jar files and the related product are both things that were produced in house. Unfortunately I'm providing about as much detail as I can. I realize that exceptions can occur for a number of reasons and asking anyone to list them all would be unreasonable. I'm just hoping someone has run into something similar and that maybe their solution would also work for me.

Comment: Without more info we're just taking wild guesses. At the very least, can you provide the name of the class that was not found, preferably the full `NoClassDefFoundError` message, or even better, a stacktrace with your proprietary class names obfuscated? Are those `product.*` classes Matlab (M-code) classes or Java classes? When you say "on the path", are the JARs on the Matlab path (wrong), the `javaclasspath` (correct), or some other path (wrong)? Static or dynamic `javaclasspath`? Java's pretty good about back-compatibiity; it's more likely a problem with your Matlab setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the difference between R2007a and R2013a is that the first uses 1.5 jre and second uses 1.6 jre.  It would be easier to help you if you provided the stack trace showing the exception.  Sometimes classes get moved around in between jvm versions, so having the actual missing classes would help in determining if the missing class is a class that was just moved around to a different package.  You could take the missing class, google it adding the same exception message as you put above and seeing who else ran into similar issues.